# Run Grunt silent / not verbose

Tags: gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner

How to run Grunt more silent?

I don't have the `--verbose` option on. Still I get a long log.

I would like to have a shorter log, ideally just log the failed specs.

Any suggestion?

I am using `grunt-karma` and `Jasmine`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update**
After some discussions in comments below I think you could do something like:

```
grunt test | grep should\|Expected > logs.txt
```

This way you'll get only the lines containing "should" or "Expected" in the log file.
Adapt this expression to match the lines you want to keep.

---

My first answer was:

Just redirect the output

Assuming your task is named 'test'

- under OS X / Linux:

  ```
  grunt test > /dev/null
  ```
- under windows command line:

  ```
  grunt test > NUL
  ```

Comment: Pascal, when I'm on Travis that can be a good idea. Do the errors get logged in this case? If not, how to make the `SUCCESS` silent/not show?

Comment: I don't think there is any logging. If you want to get the output, redirect to a file instead of Dev/null.

Comment: Locally I am already re-directing to a file. But it logs 1K+ lines since I have many Specs. I would like to not log the success ones.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can change your configuration and set **options.silently** to **true**. Take a look to the [grunt-serve npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-serve)

Comment: This answer pertains to grunt-serve, not grunt itself.